# Is setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH best way to ensure shared libraries of python package are loaded?

Tags: python, cmake, setuptools

I've a python wheel which contains shared libraries `*.so` alongwith the python module. Those shared libraries are created using `setuptools.command.build_ext` [via cmake].

Upon installing the wheel

```
pip install <name>.whl
```

All the python packages are installed in `/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/<package>/` while the shared libraries are installed in `/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

However, by default LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't search for `/opt/conda/lib/python3.6`

Is it considered a best practice to force users to update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the directory that contains shared libraries as part of python package installation? or is there a better way of handling it at compile-time so that the shared libraries are accessible for the users [who don't compile it but just install the python package] without updating the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Python doesn't need `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to search for extension modules; it is sufficient that they are placed in a dir that is in `sys.path`. site-packages is in `sys.path` unless you have a heavily modified Python distribution (e.g. isolated Python or a custom build without the `site` support).